# How to tell if a readStream has no more lines to read?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a large file (bigger than memory) line by line using the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var stream = require ('stream');

function begin(){

    var instream = fs.createReadStream(fileLocation);
    var outstream = new stream;
    outstream.readable = true;
    outstream.writable = true;

    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: instream,
        output: outstream,
        terminal: false
    });

    var ctr = 0;
    rl.on('line', function(line) { //line reading function
       //work done here.
    });
}
```

I have done some processing, and then need to write a file to disk (JSON). But I don't want to write the object before every line has been processed. All the code within the line reading function is synchronous.

How do I know when it is safe to write my file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit tricky here. An object stored in `r1` is a result of `readline.createInterface` call: that means it's an `Interface`, not a `readStream`. As `Interface` is used to interact (with some agent), you, as [written in the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_event_close_7), should listen for `close` event instead:

> **Event: close**
>
> Emitted when `close()` is called.
>
> Also emitted when the input stream receives its `end` event. The
>   `Interface` instance should be considered "finished" once this is
>   emitted. For example, when the input stream receives ^D, respectively
>   known as EOT.

So it should look like the following:

```
rl.on('line', function(line) { 
   // process emitted line
}).on('close', function() {
   // all the lines read, go on
});
```

Have you been working with `readStream` instance, you should have been listening for `end` event instead. It's emitted by `readStream` instance when the corresponding stream (created by `fs.createReadStream`) emits its own `end` event. The catch is that `Interface` object doesn't emit `end` event - as end of communication in its case means closing the channel completely.

Comment: Is this triggered before the 'close' event ?

Comment: Yes; `close` is fired, when the corresponding file descriptor is closed. In fact, not all streams emit `close` event.

Comment: This doesn't get called. Don't know why.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed the fact that `r1` is an Interface.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand your explanation. If the "end" even isn't emitted then how do I know its done ?

Comment: You should listen to `close` event on `Interface` object. This event will be emitted when the inner `ReadStream` will emit its own `end` event. Have you tried the corrected code?